# Converting synchronous Moq mocks to async

Tags: c#, moq, async-await

I am working on converting a body of synchronous asp.net code to .net 4.5 and the new async syntax.

I have a lot of test code that looks like:

```
var retVal = new Foo(bar,baz);
_myMock.Setup(x => x.DoSomething(123)).Returns(retVal);
```

When I convert the signature of DoSomething from `Foo DoSomething()` to `async Task<Foo> DoSomething()`, all of my test code has to be rewritten. My current workaround is to convert the original code to something like:

```
var retVal = new Foo(bar,baz);
_myMock.Setup(x => x.DoSomething(123))
   .Returns(new Task<Foo>(()=>retVal));
```

This is not a particularly hard transform, but it is tedious when I have thousands of tests that need to be updated.

I tried making an extension method called ReturnsAsync to do some of that form m, but I was having some type inferrence issues that I couldn't quite nail down. Is there a standard or easier way to convert this kind of mock to handle the async method better?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Moq 4.2 added a `ReturnsAsync()` extension method, so you no longer need to add your own.

Answer (score 35):

First, naming: The Task-based Asynchronous Pattern (TAP) says that all methods that are asynchronous and return `Task`s should be named ending with `Async`. So, your method should be named `DoSomethingAsync`.

Second, the constructor of `Task` creates a `Task` that is not started, you have to `Start()` it manually. If your actual `DoSomething` method does this too, that again doesn't follow TAP and it means your code won't work well with `await`. Instead, you should use `Task.Run(() => value)`, or, even better, `Task.FromResult(value)`.

Third, it would be better if you showed us your code that didn't work well, so that we could tell you where did you make a mistake.

Now, the body of `ReturnsAsync()` extension method is quite simple, but most of the work for me was in figuring out the correct types (especially since I don't know Moq). The code looks like this:

```
public static class MoqExtensions
{
    public static IReturnsResult<TMock> ReturnsAsync<TMock, TResult>(
        this IReturns<TMock, Task<TResult>> setup, TResult value)
        where TMock : class
    {
        return setup.Returns(Task.FromResult(value));
    }
}
```